# Emmet closing div's comment should come at the same line, how?

Tags: html, emmet

When I type `.container|c` and press tab, I need the result as;

```
<div class="container">

</div> <!-- /.container -->
```

Not as;

```
<div class="container">

</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Is there any way to change this behavior ? (I'm using Emmet inside brackets), I need the closing div's comment at the same line as the closing tag, not at the new line, because sometimes accidentally I add more content in between the closing div tag and the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your Emmet User settings in Sublime Text (menu option *Preferences > Package Settings > Emmet > User - Settings*):

```
  "preferences": {
    "filter.commentAfter": "<!-- /<%= attr(\"id\", \"#\") %><%= attr(\"class\", \".\") %> -->"
  }
```

Source:

http://iaintnoextra.tumblr.com/post/68089741466/automatically-add-closing-comments-to-html-using

Comment: Thank You for this answer! Originally I asked this question for brackets 2 years ago, but today when I needed the same hack for Sublime, this answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

***Edit:*** In case of Brackets follow this dirty hack, and in case of sublime follow the accepted answer.

It worked after I modified comment.js (emmet/lib/filter/comment.js)

changed code on line 19 from

```
'\n<!-- /<%= attr("id", "#") %><%= attr("class", ".") %> -->',
```

to

```
'<!-- /<%= attr("id", "#") %><%= attr("class", ".") %> -->',
```

basically removed the `\n` before the code which generate the comment, and actually this `\n` was causing the comment to come on the new line.

**Edit:** In **Visual Studio Code** add the following to your user settings,

```
"emmet.preferences": {
  "filter.commentAfter": "<!-- /[#ID][.CLASS] -->"
}
```

*Note: this answer is more than 3 years old, so the Brackets' part many or many not work.*

Comment: Anyone know how to do this in PhpStorm?